# two dimensional array with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I need a two dimensional array filled with instances of different derived types my code looks like this:

```
std::array<std::array<std::shared_ptr<Base>, 1>, 1> b;
b[1][1] = std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived(x, y));
```

The code compiles but there is some form of memory leak in `std::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared()` during the execution of the second line.

My question is: How can I properly create a two dimensional array of derived classes?

Comment: `b[1]` is out of bounds

Comment: wow :( classic case of to long programming session

Comment: Just like `T a[1][1];  a[1][1] = v;` is going out of bounds, your code is going out of bounds as well.

Comment: [OT]: You may directly use `std::make_shared<Derived>(x, y)` instead of `std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived(x, y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `b[1]` is out of bounds in your example.

In general an `std::array` (as well as C-array, `std::vector`, and others) of length `n` allows you to use indices `0, .., n - 1` on it.